# Angular 6 Dotnet core Deployment Error

Tags: .net-core, angular6

I am developing Angular application with DotNet Core. In the development environment Application works fine, but upon publishing to IIS server receiving the following Error(Internal error while loading script file in index.html) 
IMG->
[Website Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C02lM.png)

IIS folder structure is a follows.
[inetpub folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6A7s.png) 
[inetpub folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Np4q.png)

Index.html code is a follwos

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WebPayzUI</title>
  <base href="/WebPayz/ClientApp/dist">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.0243bd00007c5e1092e8.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.83183756596ff1996025.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.385b291e179030219400.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.e9e2c4382e2ff45e82db.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may need to provide the options "--base-href" and "--deploy-url" while taking your build. Care to share how your are taking angular build?

Comment: If you have a database connection, make sure you have a database, and a valid connection string and the App pool has security access to it. The app deployed to IIS can't connect to the VS express database.

Answer (score 0):

base href="/WebPayz/"

update base href to the above in your index.html file